# A Nefarious Riley

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, acrostic

I was paying a visit to the WorldBuilding.SE site and found [a post that was quite interesting](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/125884/how-can-i-ensure-my-evil-tower-is-always-stormy). Now, I will link the post after an answer has been accepted for those who would like to go read it. As always, good luck to all of you!

> Look for the prefix, it lives within me; peer to the end, as far as you can see.
>
> Into the darkness, the infix revealed; a volcano perhaps, in a small field.
>
> Viewing the suffix, a thunderous cloud? Not really too sure, an illness is found.
>
> Even apart, afraid you must be; for I always have, my minions with me.

Comment: I was also checking out some posts on world building as well!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are

> Evil(lol, but your not)

Look for the prefix, it lives within me; peer to the end, as far as you can see.

> E in "me".

Into the darkness, the infix revealed; a volcano perhaps, in a small field.

> Vil?

Viewing the suffix, a thunderous cloud? Not really too sure, an illness is found.

> Il

Even apart, afraid you must be; for I always have, my minions with me.

> evil

Acrostic

> spells evil backwards so "Live".

Comment: #FastestGunOfTheWest

Comment: The infix is the only thing wrong. Congrats again! Do I need to step my game back up or are the other ones too difficult?

Comment: Maybe do a math problem? (Nah, I only say that because I am good at those lol)

Comment: Well, perhaps you should both go visit [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72728/a-riley-some-math-and-a-confusing-note) again; I opened a bounty on it this morning lol.

Comment: How dare you call PerpetualJ evil!

Comment: @PotatoLatte excuse you, I'm pretty sure I got that one (but my memory is bad) ;P

Comment: @El-Guest Wanna join us in codenames?

Comment: @PerpetualJ, is my infix better? :)

Comment: Dinnertime now @PotatoLatte but I can be around in 30 minutes or so!

Comment: @El-Guest I'm not really playing, they are just short someone because I have to go

Comment: Okay well let me sign in @PotatoLatte

Comment: @El-Guest You don't use this account?

Comment: I do, I just had to find the chatroom @PotatoLatte